# How to split templates into separate files in Meteor

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

I am using Meteor.js as well as router.js (the package) in order to render other pages of my website. However, all my templates (the other pages) are in one html file. How can I split my templates into different html files and still use router.js?

One sample router configuration for a template is:

```
Router.route('/events', 
function(){
  this.render('eventsPage');
},
{
  onAfterAction: function() {
    document.title = 'Events';
  }
});
```

Where /events is the url associated with the template 'eventsPage'. How can I put the eventsPage template into a separate html file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have each template in separate file, Meteor detects all of your html code.

> HTML files in a Meteor application are treated quite a bit differently from a server-side framework. Meteor scans all the HTML files in your directory for three top-level elements: , , and . The head and body sections are separately concatenated into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on initial page load.

Read more: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/whatismeteor

So your HTML file structure depends mostly on your preference.

You should also take a look at:
http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/structure/

Comment: So would I just make a seperate html file with no head tags and just define within a template?

Comment: Exactly, just make some templates in separate html files, Meteor will be able to access them

Comment: Well, meteor 1.8 cannot find separate template files or separate js files so far. Ran the book example twice and it failed with all sorts of errors in the console until I consolidated all the templates and code into the central files. I am hoping that the book is just tragically out of date (I sprang for the whole enchilada and so far I am feeling rather ripped off) ...

Comment: The links I provided were valid in 2015, newer Meteor versions introduced pretty big changes and I guess most of this book may be out of date. You should refer to current Meteor documentation